# Overwriting a range of cells based on another range of cells within Google App Script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to auto update a task tracker which contains a "status column" and a "days remaining" column. The status column is updated by the task owner to establish what is the current status of any particular task.

Once the due date is passed (and the "days remaining" column is -1 or less I want the status column to override itself and to display " Overdue".

I've written the below code but it's currently not changing when I run the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
function overdue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('task_tracker')
  var statusRange = sheet.getRange('J23:J50')
  var overdueRange = sheet.getRange ('L23:L50')

  for (var i=0; i< overdueRange.length; i++) {
    var days =overdueRange[i];

    for (var k=0; k< statusRange.length; k++) {
      var status = statusRange[k];
      if (days <0) {
        status.setValue(' Overdue');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Range` is not iterable. You need to get the values as array and iterate the array, create a modified array and set back the modified array to  the new range.

Comment: @TheMaster I have iterated the range but now seeing a new issue. I would appreciate a second set of eyes to establish where I'm going wrong. Thanks! I've updated the question with the additional code

Comment: You're looping in a nested manner. Loop executes exponentially. Use a single loop and use the counter `i` to access the corresponding range in the other range.

Comment: I have reproduced your most recent code and run it against a mock-spreadsheet configured in the way you have described and I seem to be getting the behaviour you were originally after. Is this question now solved?

Comment: @JamesHearn yes this now runs as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @jackb Do not edit the question to add a answer. Consider adding a answer  below, in the answer box explaining the concepts that helped you solve the problem. See [answer]. We have a strict structure for question and answer spaces.

Answer (score 1):

By iterating both ranges by adding `.getValues()` to both ranges and looping once we achieved the required result.

```
function overdue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('task_tracker');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var statusRange = sheet.getRange('J18:J'+ lastRow).getValues();
  var overdueRange = sheet.getRange ('L18:L' + lastRow).getValues();

  for (var i=0; i< statusRange.length; i++) {
    var days =overdueRange[i];
    var status = statusRange[i];
    var row = i+18
    
    if (days <0) {
      sheet.getRange('J' + row).setValue(' Overdue');
    }
  }
}
```